# error: variable cv::cuda::GpuMat has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: ros, opencv, cuda

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use the CUDA implementation for OpenCV on the NVidia TX1.

Using cv::Mat, the minimal example below works, but with cv::cuda::GpuMat it returns errors when comiling:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include <cv_bridge/cv_bridge.h>
#include <image_transport/image_transport.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

void imageCallback(const sensor_msgs::ImageConstPtr& original_image){
    cv_bridge::CvImagePtr cv_ptr;
    try     {       
        cv_ptr = cv_bridge::toCvCopy(original_image);   
    }   catch (cv_bridge::Exception& e)     {       
        ROS_ERROR("test::main.cpp::cv_bridge exception: %s", e.what());
        return;     
    }   
    cv::cuda::GpuMat yuvImage = cv_ptr->image;
    cv::cuda::GpuMat rgbImage;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "test");
    ros::NodeHandle n;
    ros::Subscriber image_sub = n.subscribe("/camera/image_raw", 1, imageCallback);
    ros::spin();
}
```

The errors I get with `catkin build`are:

```
/home/wim/catkin-ws/src/test/src/test.cpp: In function ‘void imageCallback(const ImageConstPtr&)’:
/home/wim/catkin-ws/src/test/src/test.cpp:19:34: error: variable ‘cv::cuda::GpuMat yuvImage’ has initializer but incomplete type
  cv::cuda::GpuMat yuvImage(tmpMat);
                                  ^
/home/wim/catkin-ws/src/test/src/test:20:19: error: aggregate ‘cv::cuda::GpuMat rgbImage’ has incomplete type and cannot be defined
  cv::cuda::GpuMat rgbImage;
```

What am I doing wrong?
The OpenCV4Tegra is installed and no other OpenCV version as far as I can see
Should I include something more?

[edit]Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(test)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  std_msgs
  cv_bridge
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(test src/test.cpp)
add_dependencies(test ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${PROJECT_NAME}_gen$
target_link_libraries(test
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
)
```

[/edit]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/274474/error:-variable-cv::cuda::gpumat-has-initializer-but-incomplete-type/) by [WLemkens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4068/wlemkens/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2017-10-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is `cv::cuda::GpuMat` working from a standard c++ file? I think it could be that you installed OpenCV4Tegra wrong or maybe there is an issue of your CMakeList.txt, would you mind posting it?
PS. I used [this](https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d6/d15/tutorial_building_tegra_cuda.html) to build OpenCV4Tegra with no problem at all.

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [WLemkens](https://answers.ros.org/users/4068/wlemkens/) on 2017-11-04**:
What do you mean  with "a standard c++ file"?

Is the OpenCV installed by default on the TX1 not the OpenCV4Tegra? I did not install a custom OpenCV.